# cant understand the triagle number enumerator yielder yield

Tags: ruby

unable to understand this code how it works.

```
triangular_numbers = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
 number = 0
 count = 1
 loop do
    number += count
    count += 1
    yielder.yield number  
  end
 end
5.times { print triangular_numbers.next, " " }
```

cant understand how `yielder` works for this block. how its `yield` work for `number` variable. how do loop runs 5 times. and how `triangular_number.next` works for the first time.

Comment: The block passed to `Enumerator.new` is executed when you call `next` for the first time. Execution is however paused each time `yielder.yield` is called, so `loop` doesn't keep running. Calling `next` from the outside effectively causes the internal `loop` to do one iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An [enumerator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerator.html) is basically something that you can call `next` on and get something back. The `yielder` is the mechanism where it gives something back when `next` is called. Execution stops at the `yield` until the next call to `next`.

**Farfetched analogy**

You can think of an `enumerator` as a **ticket machine** like when you're waiting in line at a government office. When you press a button (`next`) it gives you a **ticket**. Inside the machine there's a **chute** where the ticket comes out. But the ticket machine is not constantly printing tickets. It waits for the button to be pressed before it prints the next ticket and puts it through the chute.

In this case the analogous code would be:

```
ticket_machine = Enumerator.new do |chute|
 ticket = 0
 loop do
    #print_ticket
    chute.yield ticket #waits here until you hit the button
    ticket += 1
  end
 end
5.times { print ticket_machine.next, " " } # gets 5 tickets
```

Your code sample is basically the same thing, but instead of issuing tickets, it's issuing triangular numbers. The **chute** is the `yielder` where the numbers get passed through.

This is not the only way to use an enumerator, [check the docs for more.](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerator.html)

Answer (score 4):

`Enumerator::new` accepts a block. This block, when run, receives an `Enumerator::Yielder`, which has a method `#yield`.

When the `Enumerator#next` is called, the block is executed, up to the first `Enumerator::Yielder#yield`. The execution is paused there; the value given to `yield` is the value that `next` returns. When you call `next` again on the same `Enumerator`, the execution is resumed, and proceeds until it encounters `yield` again.

---

So in your case, `5.times` executes its block, intending to repeat it five times. `triangular_numbers.next` is called; this starts the execution of the block above. `number` and `count` are set to their values, and an infinite loop is started. `number` is set to `1`, `count` is set to `2`, and then we find `yielder.yield`. This pauses the execution of the block, and returns the control back to where `next` was called inside `5.times` loop. `next` returns `1`, because `yielder.yield` received `number` (`1`).

Second time through the `5.times` loop, we want to print the next number. This stops the main execution line, and resumes the enumerator block from just after `yielder.yield`. The infinite loop continues; `number` is `3`, `count` is `3`, `yielder.yield` pauses the enumerator and resumes the main code. `next` gets `3`, which gets printed.

Third, fourth and fifth time through the `5.times` loop are exactly the same.

After five iterations, `5.times` loop ends, and the execution proceeds past it. The enumerator is paused, ready to give the next number in sequence, if you ever call `next` on it again (since it has an infinite loop), but you never do, and the program exits.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain what it does bit by bit, so you can try to wrap your head around it.

```
Enumerator.new do |yielder|
end
```

So you instantiate an enumerator that will work over a variable called `yielder`.

Inside its scope you set some local vars (that will be kept as the object is reused):

```
 number = 0
 count = 1
```

And then you set a loop that increments `number` by `count` and `count` by `1` and then call yield over your argument passing `number` to it as an argument.

```
loop do
  number += count
  count += 1
  yielder.yield number  
end
```

`5.times` repeats the block passed to it 5 times. The block

```
-> { print triangular_numbers.next, " " }
```

calls `print` that takes `n` args and concatenates the parts to form a string, but does not append a newline.

The first argument is our enumerator next interaction (`triangular_numbers.next`), which will compute the current number and call yield on the `Enumerator::Yielder` that's implicitly created handling the control back to the calling `Fiber` along with any args that got passed to it.

(All Enumerators are implemented as "Fibers" on MRI)

So that `yielder.yield` call is similar to a `Fiber.yield` call and will allow the  `5.times` loop to run and return the `number` 1.

Comment: "(All Enumerators are implemented as "Fibers" on MRI)" - nitpick, but not quite: both `Enumerator` and `Fiber` are implemented in C, a layer below Ruby classes; but they share a lot of the underlying C code (i.e. `enumerator.c` uses functions defined in `cont.c` (named after the now deprecated `callcc`, which is like grandfather to fibers, which now also houses the underlying fiber code).

Comment: True, but way too technical for the short post. =)

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a piece of code to the already clear explanation provided:

```
my_enum = Enumerator.new do |whatever_name_for_the_yielder|
  n = 0
  loop do
    whatever_name_for_the_yielder.yield "Return this: #{n}"
    n += 1
  end
end

puts my_enum.next #=> Return this: 0
puts my_enum.next #=> Return this: 1
puts my_enum.next #=> Return this: 2
```

When you provide an end to the iteration, it stops with an error:

```
my_enum2 = Enumerator.new do |whatever_name_for_the_yielder|
  2.times do |n|
    whatever_name_for_the_yielder.yield "Return this: #{n}"
  end
  puts "Outside the loop"
end

puts my_enum2.next #=> Return this: 0
puts my_enum2.next #=> Return this: 1
puts my_enum2.next #=> Outside the loop
#=> ERROR: .....in `next': iteration reached an end (StopIteration)
```